# Conditions for being an unramified extensions

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I'm not sure of the following:
If I have a non-archimedean normed field $K$ of charateristic zero with residue field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$.  If $\alpha$ is an element in some finite extension of $K$ such that there exists a non negative integer $h$ with $\alpha^h \in K$ then, $\alpha$ is an element of an unramified extension of $K$ ?

Comment: Look at $K=\Bbb{Q}_p$ then $\Bbb{Q}_p(\alpha)/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is unramified iff $O_K/(p)$ is a field iff $K= \Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ with $\beta \in O_K$ and its monic minimal polynomial $f\in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ is separable modulo $p$. From Hensel lemma (= gradient descent) it means we can lift a root of $f\bmod p$ to a unique root of $f$ and we understand the Galois group of the splitting field easily from this. Exercice : show that if $p\nmid h$ and $\alpha^h \in K$ then $K(\alpha)/K$ is unramified.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $K=\Bbb Q_2$, and $\alpha=\sqrt2$. Then $K(\alpha)/K$ is ramified.

Comment: Ok obviously ! Thanks !